# Creating master ID in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, matching

Let's say, I have a data table with below columns:

```
EMAIL          PHONE          IP
123@ABC.COM    123456         0.0.0.0
123@ABC.COM    123456         0.0.0.1
123@ABC.COM    654321         0.0.0.0
321@ABC.COM    123456         0.0.0.0
000@ABC.COM    000000         1.1.1.1
000@ABC.COM    000001         1.1.1.2
```

I want to create a table on top of that data table, which has the master ID. The rule is as long as one of each attribute (Email, Phone, IP) is matched then they will have the same master ID.

For example:

```
EMAIL          PHONE          IP          Master_ID 
123@ABC.COM    123456         0.0.0.0     1
123@ABC.COM    123456         0.0.0.1     1
123@ABC.COM    654321         0.0.0.0     1 
321@ABC.COM    123456         0.0.0.0     1
000@ABC.COM    000000         1.1.1.1     2
000@ABC.COM    000001         1.1.1.2     2
```

Is there any suggestion on how can I get it done by just using query/function in Oracle?

Comment: Your logic seems to be based on an ORDER of the rows. There is no "natural" order of rows in a table in any relational database; you must provide an explicit order if one is to be used in your logic. Do you have one more column, with something like a sequence number, or a timestamp, that should be used for that purpose? As stated the problem does not make sense.

Comment: Maybe you misunderstand. There's no order here. Basically I have records come in with 3 attributes (email, phone and ip). As long as I have 1 matching attribute with an existing records, I need them to have the same master_id.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstand, but I doubt it. More likely you misunderstand. When you say "I have records come in" and "existing records" this means some records are "existing" and others, different ones, are "coming in." This means some records are there before others. IN WHAT ORDER? So, for example, why isn't the Master_ID of 000@ABC.COM equal to 1, and the Master_ID for 123@ABC.COM equal to 2?

Comment: Yeah, it can be like that, or whatever ID, I'm also thinking of making it generated by sys_guid(). I need it to be a UNIQUE ID. There's no order in the picture here. And yes, I have existing records and will have a lot more coming in.

Comment: What you want probably doesn't make sense. Consider the following situation: just looking at phone (simplified) and IP (simplified) - what if you currently have two rows, with the values 123-45 and 1.23 and 123-89 and 1.44? They have nothing in common, so the first one may have master_id = 1 and the second master_id = 2. Now another row comes in, with values 123-45 and 1.44. What master_id should it get, 1 or 2? It should really get both 1 and 2; now the original two rows are "connected" through this third row. Should all three rows now have the same master_id? If no, why not? (What logic?)

Comment: You can create simple trigger on table insertion, where you check whether you already have a matching row (i. a. select first row with email == inserted email) and if so, assign the same master_id and repeat that for every column. Although, it's extremely inefficient, and there is a multi-column matching problem, as mathguy noticed.

Comment: @mathguy: I see your point. In this case, I would make all the three connected, and the newer master ID will be merged with the older one.

Comment: Is it necessary to use only query/function? Do you need to process new data after current table transformation?